# Modify HTMLBody for Inline Response in outlook

Tags: c#, outlook, ms-word, vsto, mailitem

I am trying to modify the body of an inline reply in Outlook. I need to insert HTML into the inline response editor.

I am trying to do it like this:

```
                    var explorer = application.ActiveExplorer();
                    MailItem item = explorer.ActiveInlineResponse;
                    item.Subject = "INLINE SUBJECT";
                    item.HTMLBody = item.HTMLBody.Replace("Test", "INLINE BODY");
```

For some reason, the item.Subject is set correctly but the body doesn't get set. I used the replace to make sure I wasn't messing up the HTML - I thought I would just try to replace a word with another word without modifying the HTML.

I tried changing the text in the inline response using `ActiveInlineResponseWordEditor` which worked - but the problem is that I need to insert HTML and I dont know how to do that using the word editor object.

Any ideas of how I can either successfully modify the `HtmlBody` or insert html using `ActiveInlineResponseWordEditor` ?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```
Outlook.MailItem newmail = item.Reply();
newmail.BodyFormat = Outlook.OlBodyFormat.olFormatHTML;
newmail.HTMLBody = item.HTMLBody.Replace("Test", "INLINE BODY");
```

You can try getting the reply of the mail and doing changes in that.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the `Save` method of the MailItem class.